# Field-level cypher statements do not work when accepting parameters in Apollo-server

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher, apollo-server, grandstack

The cypher directive on a field-level does not work as [expected](https://grandstack.io/docs/guide-graphql-schema-design/).

Minimal example:

```
type Question {
  id: ID! @id
  required: Boolean
  testing(someId: ID!): Boolean
    @cypher(statement: """
      MATCH (q:Question {id:$someId}) RETURN q.required
    """)
}
```

When running the below query, I'm getting an error.

```
{
  Question {
    testing(someId: "12345678-1234-1234-1234-0123456789ab")
  }
}
```

This is the error log as seen in the Apollo Playground:

> {   "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Invalid input '_someId': expected\n  "!="\n  "%"\n  "*"\n  "+"\n  ","\n  "-"\n  "."\n  "/"\n  ":"\n
> "<"\n  "<="\n  "<>"\n  "="\n  "=~"\n  ">"\n  ">="\n
> "AND"\n  "CONTAINS"\n  "ENDS"\n  "IN"\n  "IS"\n  "OR"\n
> "STARTS"\n  "XOR"\n  "["\n  "^"\n  "}" (line 1, column 195
> (offset: 194))\n"MATCH (`question`:`Question`) RETURN `question`
> {testing: apoc.cypher.runFirstColumn("MATCH (q:Question {id:$someId})
> RETURN q.required", {this: question, cypherParams: $cypherParams,
> someId: $1_someId}, false)} AS `question`"\n
>
> ^",
> "locations": [
> {
> "line": 2,
> "column": 3
> }
> ],
> "path": [
> "Question"
> ],
> "extensions": {
> "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
> "exception": {
> "code": "Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError",
> "name": "Neo4jError",
> "stacktrace": [
> "Neo4jError: Invalid input '_someId': expected",
> "  "!="",
> "  "%"",
> "  "*"",
> "  "+"",
> "  ","",
> "  "-"",
> "  "."",
> "  "/"",
> "  ":"",
> "  "<"",
> "  "<="",
> "  "<>"",
> "  "="",
> "  "=~"",
> "  ">"",
> "  ">="",
> "  "AND"",
> "  "CONTAINS"",
> "  "ENDS"",
> "  "IN"",
> "  "IS"",
> "  "OR"",
> "  "STARTS"",
> "  "XOR"",
> "  "["",
> "  "^"",
> "  "}" (line 1, column 195 (offset: 194))",
> ""MATCH (`question`:`Question`) RETURN `question` {testing: apoc.cypher.runFirstColumn("MATCH (q:Question {id:$someId})
> RETURN q.required", {this: question, cypherParams: $cypherParams,
> someId: $1_someId}, false)} AS `question`"",
> "                                                                                                                                                                                                   ^",
> ": ",
> "    at captureStacktrace (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/neo4j-driver-core/lib/result.js:239:17)",
> "    at new Result (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/neo4j-driver-core/lib/result.js:59:23)",
> "    at newCompletedResult (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/neo4j-driver-core/lib/transaction.js:372:12)",
> "    at Object.run (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/neo4j-driver-core/lib/transaction.js:226:20)",
> "    at Transaction.run (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/neo4j-driver-core/lib/transaction.js:98:34)",
> "    at _callee3$ (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/index.js:226:35)",
> "    at tryCatch (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)",
> "    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)",
> "    at Generator.next (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:118:21)",
> "    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/asyncToGenerator/index.js:5:24)",
> "    at _next (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/asyncToGenerator/index.js:27:9)",
> "    at /home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/asyncToGenerator/index.js:34:7",
> "    at new Promise ()",
> "    at new F (/home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:36:28)",
> "    at /home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/asyncToGenerator/index.js:23:12",
> "    at /home/m1/citizentric/grand-housing/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/index.js:241:30"
> ]
> }
> }
> }   ],   "data": {
> "Question": null   } }

My package.json includes these versions:

```
"apollo-server": "^2.25.0",
"apollo-server-core": "^2.25.0",
"graphql-tag": "^2.12.5",
"neo4j-driver": "^4.3.1",
"neo4j-graphql-js": "^2.19.2",
```

Top-level queries (with arguments) and field-level queries with the cypher decorator work fine as long as these do not accept parameters.
I was under the impression that this has worked earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The library `"neo4j-graphql-js": "^2.19.2"` does not seem to pass on custom parameters unless you create a mutation. Try the following way:

```
type Question {
  id: ID! @id
  required: Boolean
}

extend type Mutation {
  testing(someId: ID!): Boolean
    @cypher(
      statement: """
      MATCH (q:Question {id: $someId}) RETURN q.required
      """
    )
}
```

```
mutation {
  testing (someId: "12345678-1234-1234-1234-0123456789ab") 
}
```

Comment: We're using top-level queries with custom parameters just fine. It's just not working on a type's field-level.

Comment: I guess it wasn't a feature in in neo4j-graphql-js in its last versions. It's a library under rapid development so there can be many breaking changes. However I believe you can accomplish many things in a different way, even if the current features do not allow to do it as elegantly.